# Arrange dates in a sequential order

Tags: java, android

I am storing the dates that are entered by the user using a `DatePicker` in a file & reading the contents from the file and showing it into my history page. Please find the image attached

I need to arrange those dates in a proper sequence depending on the entry on the left hand side. Please help me for the same.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: do you mean **sorting the dates**?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `java.util.Date` to operate your dates it should be easy, as `Date` implements `Comparable`. So you'll just need to read your values into a `List` and then perform a `Collections.sort(list);` to get your dates sorted in an ascending order.

Comment: I am saving these dates into a file and then later I am reading it. IF user adds date as in above case then what should I do ?

Comment: why exactly are you writing the dates to a file.?

Comment: Ok, let's see if I'm getting it right: 1.the user chooses a date 2.the date is saved to a file with other dates 3. you read the file and display the values. Right? If so, read the dates from the file into an `ArrayList`, sort it and then display your messages.